# Significant direct effect and non significant TOTAL effect

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, amos

[image: Path diagram]I have a cross-lagged model with 3 waves and two variables. Here the regression`s paths.

```
  CEE3 ~ a * CEE1 
  CEE5 ~ b * CEE3  
  TM3  ~ c * TM1  
  TM3  ~ d * CEE1  
  CEE3 ~ e * TM1  
  TM5  ~ f * TM3
  TM5  ~ g * CEE3  
  CEE5 ~ h * TM3
```

The path "g" is significant (p<.01) BUT the TOTAL effect of CEE3 to TM5 is not! As you can see there is no way of having any indirect effects. How can this happen. The TOTAL effect is the direct effect plus any indirect effect, BUT if there is no indirect effect the TOTAL effect should be the direct effect, am I right? How to interpret that?
Thank you for your support.
Regards,

Comment: It's kind of hard to interpret the model. Do you have a path diagram? (The only way I can work out what is happening is to draw one).

Comment: Also, is this the complete model? Was it saturated?

Comment: (I reformatted the text to make it easier to read).

Comment: Sorry @JeremyMiles I didn´t come back earlier...I just couldn´t add any picture to my post. This is the complete model. if you let me know how can I add a picture to mey post I can sen one. Many thanks once again

Comment: I was doing some research and maybe the problem here is talking about total/direct/indirect effects doesn´t make much sense in this kind of models?? We should only take into account the paths coefficients??

Comment: Autoregressive paths= CEE1-->CEE3-->CEE5 and TM1-->TM3-->TM5;Cross-lagged paths: CEE1-->TM3; CEE3-->TM5;TM1-->CEE3;TM3-->CEE5 Maybe this can help to make an idea of the model) –

Comment: If this is the complete model, you've missed out the within wave correlations, e.g. TM3 ~~~ CM3

Comment: Maybe with this diagram can be easier. Please only consider those new variables name: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i4Y5qwhiIzEYTQ_UC73SrfAR9TwR9-MK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I added the diagram to the question. Your syntax doesn't look like the diagram. Your syntax has no covariances, the diagram does.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong when I copied and pasted the syntax

Comment: My question is now about TOTAL effects in this model. Is there ay reason why the path EC T2 to TM T3 is significant BUT NOT the TOTAL effect of EC T2 to TM T3??

Comment: Make there any sense to talk about indirect effects in this kind of model?? I mean would be possible to find the indirect effect of EC T1 to TM T3 through EC T2 (.23*.23) and TM T2 (.29*.39) ??

Comment: Yes, I think it does make sense to talk about indirect effects.

Comment: OH thanks!!! Any literature where this kind of interpretation was done with 2V3W cross-lagged panel model?? I only find many literature regarding mediation and including a third variable. On the other hand, how can be possible that direct path from EC T2 to TM T3 is significant BUT NOT the total effect of EC T2 to TM T3??

Comment: That sort of thing is discussed in the mediation literature, and it's why the total effect being significant is no longer considered something worth testing before looking for mediation.